# Jade - как создать таблицу

Tags: gulp, jade

Как создать такой HTML код, используя Jade.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
  <th>User</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>haacki47</td>
</tr>
```

Я использую компилятор gulp-jade. 
Конечно можно создать таблицу используя такой код на Jade

```
table
tr
  th #
  th
    input(type='checkbox')
  th User
tr
  th 1
  th
    input(type='checkbox')
  th haacki47
tr
  th 2
  th
    input(type='checkbox')
  th Newuser
```

Но это будет не практично, хотелось бы создать такую таблицу используя циклы и еще что то, не знаю что именно. Знал сделал бы сам. По этому прошу у вас помощи.

Answer (score 3):

```
table
    each ent, num in [{"id": "#", "nick": "User"}]
        tr
            th= ent.id
            th: input(type='checkbox')
            th= ent.nick

    each ent, num in [{"id": "1", "nick": "haacki47"}, {"id": "2", "nick": "Newuser"}]
        tr

            td= ent.id
            td: input(type='checkbox')
            td= ent.nick
```

http://codepen.io/Zoxon/pen/vLNWwe